# Angular Material not displaying correct style

Tags: html, angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material

I'm trying to use Angular Material for an Autocomplete component in a template based form, but it basically does nothing to the style of the input.

I've imported all modules and the style as explained in the [official docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started), but no changes, this is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I want:

[image]

And this is my code:

html:

```
 <mat-form-field>
      <input type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" name="myFirstMaterialComp" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
 </mat-form-field>
 <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let location of locations | async" [value]="location.toponymName">
              <span>{{ location.toponymName }}</span> |
       </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

And I have all my imports in ts as well as the import for the css class, I'm sure it's something very obvious that I'm missing, but I just can't figure out what...

**EDIT** for clarity:

I have imported the angular theme with the line provided in the docs:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: Material theme is missing

Comment: Nope, that's imported in my vendor.css, as mentioned in description of question, I will add line for clarity anyway

Comment: Did you follow the Angular Material get started steps?https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started, step 4 is what you are missing

Comment: @Kld please see edit in question

Comment: Are you sure that none of your other dependencies are overriding the css on the input?

Comment: @Edric it was one of my thoughts, but how can I check that?  Plus I don't have a class defined for input in the tag

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome usuallyd

Answer (score 0):

You use autocomplete with material input, so you will need to import both:

```
import {MatAutocompleteModule, MatInputModule} from '@angular/material';
```